# Rice Theorem - What is non-trivial property?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, rice-theorem

Every nontrivial property of the recursively enumerable languages is undecidable.

What exactly is nontrivial property?

Comment: A property that holds for every machine or holds for none is trivial. Rice's theorem does not apply to such a property.

Comment: @Untitled: please make this an answer.

Comment: For example, the [Wikipedia page on Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) explains this at least twice. You are expected to research the problem on your own before posting here. If you did research it on your own, let us know what you looked at and what you didn't understand, so we can give more specific help.

Comment: This a place for questions that can not (easily) be answered by searching Wikipedia or opening a textbook. Also, we have the answer on here already. (Also, your problem illustrates why explanations in "simple English" should never be given/read alone when it comes to TCS.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A property that holds for every machine or holds for none is trivial. Rice's theorem does not apply to such a property.

To see why, note that such a property can be decided by a very simple Turing machine, which accepts/rejects every Turing machine representation.